# Which version of SBT ? scala2.13.3

Tags: scala, sbt

According to the SBT website, the latest version of SBT is 1.3.13. Is this available in 2.13.3, the latest version of Scala?

Comment: The version of sbt and the version of Scala are two different and unrelated things. Just try to always use the latest of both.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes.**

You can download the latest version of sbt (1.3.13 for now)

https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html

and use it for your project if you write in the file *project/build.properties*

```
sbt.version = 1.3.13
```

Also you can write in the file *build.sbt*

```
scalaVersion := "2.13.3"
```

Currently it's the latest version of Scala

https://www.scala-lang.org/download/all.html

So you will be using the latest versions both of Scala and sbt.

Some sideways remarks. Sbt is written in Scala itself. For sbt 1.3.13 it's [Scala 2.12.10](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v1.3.13/project/Dependencies.scala#L7-L9). Most probably this version of Scala is irrelevant to you. It's relevant only to those who develop sbt or write plugins to sbt etc. Also the file *build.sbt* is a script in Scala using version of Scala specified in *project/build.sbt* i.e. in the build file of meta-project ([sbt is recursive](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Organizing-Build.html#sbt+is+recursive)). It should be Scala 2.12.x because of the binary compatibility with the version of Scala sbt is written in, i.e. from 2.12.0 to 2.12.12. So you can write `val x: 1 = 1` (singleton types, a Scala-2.13 feature) in your project Scala code but can't in *build.sbt*. In this sense the answer is **No**.

Comment: which version of sbt is compatible with scala version 2.12.14